# MongoDB - match records based on array of objects property value

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have to write a query for finding out documents based on array of objects property values. For example, I have following documents -

```
[{
    status: 'active',
    disabled: false,
    contents: [
    {
        label: 'Name',
        slug: 'name',
        value: 'ABC',
    },
    {
        label: 'Slug',
        slug: 'slug',
        value: 'abc',
    },
    {
        label: 'Featured Product',
        slug: 'featured-product',
        value: 'Yes',
    },
    {
        label: 'In Stock',
        slug: 'in-stock',
        value: 'Yes',
    }]
},
{
    status: 'active',
    disabled: false,
    contents: [
        {
            label: 'Name',
            slug: 'name',
            value: 'XYZ',
        },
        {
            label: 'Slug',
            slug: 'slug',
            value: 'xyz',
        },
        {
            label: 'Featured Product',
            slug: 'featured-product',
            value: 'No',
        },
        {
            label: 'In Stock',
            slug: 'in-stock',
            value: 'Yes',
        }
    ]
}]
```

Now, I have to find out documents where `slug` is `featured-product`, `value` is `Yes` & `slug` is `in-stock`, `value` is `Yes`.

I wrote a query to find out documents where `slug` is `featured-product` but having difficulties when applying another condition - `slug` is `in-stock`, `value` is `Yes`.

Here is my query that is working fine -

```
db.items.aggregate([
{
    $lookup: {
        from: "contents",
        localField: "_id",
        foreignField: "itemId",
        as: "contents"
    }
},
{
    $match: {
        contents: {
            $elemMatch: {
                "slug": "featured-product",
                "value": "No"
            },
        }
    }
}])
```

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

Here is the result of `items` collection after `lookup`. I am adding some parts of the whole result -

```
[
    {
        _id: ObjectId("648d6d0f221f77c425aac3b9"),
        status: 'active',
        disabled: false,
        createdBy: ObjectId("64898858d1c108f6eec71217"),
        createdAt: 2023-06 - 17T08: 21: 35.355Z,
        updatedAt: 2023-06 - 17T08: 21: 35.355Z,
        contents: [
            {
                _id: ObjectId("648d6d0f221f77c425aac3cf"),
                label: 'Name',
                itemId: ObjectId("648d6d0f221f77c425aac3b9"),
                slug: 'name',
                value: 'V-NECK DRESS',
                trashed: 'false',
                status: 1,
                widgetId: ObjectId("648d4111ae1b9fb2af57f8f7"),
                createdAt: 2023-06 - 17T08: 21: 35.374Z,
                updatedAt: 2023-06 - 17T10:09:02.733Z,
                disabled: 'false'
            },
            {
                ....
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        ......
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have got quite a bit a hacky solution for you:

1. Duplicate your contents field by using the `$addFields` stage to keep the original array in the root of the documents
2. Unwind your duplicated field
3. Match documents with your two or conditions
4. Group your documents by id and add the `count` field.
5. Then match if the `count` field equals 2 (that means that 2 array elemens of one document have been matched.
6. After just do some projections to meet your output requirements

After all, the aggregation looks something like this:

```
db.items.aggregate(
    [
        {
            "$addFields" : {
                "content" : "$contents"
            }
        }, 
        {
            "$unwind" : {
                "path" : "$content"
            }
        }, 
        {
            "$match" : {
                "$or" : [
                    {
                        "content.slug" : "featured-product",
                        "content.value" : "Yes"
                    },
                    {
                        "content.slug" : "in-stock",
                        "content.value" : "Yes"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }, 
        {
            "$group" : {
                "_id" : "$_id",
                "document" : {
                    "$first" : "$$ROOT"
                },
                "count" : {
                    "$sum" : NumberInt(1)
                }
            }
        }, 
        {
            "$match" : {
                "count" : NumberInt(2)
            }
        }, 
        {
            "$unset" : [
                "document.content"
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "$replaceRoot" : {
                "newRoot" : "$document"
            }
        }
    ]
```